# How to get past push() generated keys so I can update or remove it in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Realtime Database]

This is my structure in Firebase Realtime Database. My problem is that I can't get past those unique keys so I can update or remove the values with corresponding buttons in my app with Kotlin.

I've tried with this code but nothing happens. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
 private fun deleteData() {
        val key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Utfordringer").push().key ?: return

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Utfordringer")
            .child("$key")
            .child("kategori")
            .child("utfordring")
            .removeValue()
```

Comment: The code snippet generates a unique key and then deleted a node that it never created in the first place.It's not clear from the code snippet what you want to do.

Comment: That's probably right. I am trying to get the reference to "kategori" and "utfordring" so I can update or remove it.

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I was busy studying for my exams.. But yes, I will accept it. And thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your current code doesn't work: when you call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Utfordringer")` you're generating a new key. Since this key won't exist in the database yet, no data is deleted. You'll instead need to know the existing key of the node in order to delete data under it.

---

An alternative to Doug's approach: if you call `deleteData` from within your UI for an existing node, you'll want to instead keep the key of the node available too.

So for example: say you load the `Utfordringer` from the database, you loop over them and add their `utfordring` and `kategori` to the UI. You'll also at that point want to keep the `key` of each `Utfordringer` child node in a way that you can associate it with the UI element when the user clicks it.

A common way to do that is by keeping lists of keys and values, or a single list of the snapshots from the database:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Utfordringer")
val list = arrayListOf<DataSnapshot>()
ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            list.add(snapshot)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
        // ...
    }
})
```

Now with this, the `list` contains the snapshots from the database, and you can use that to show them in the UI (with an adapter) **and** to look them up later when needed. So when the user now clicks an item in the UI, and you know the position of the item they clicked, you can look up and delete the corresponding `Utfordringer` child node in the database with:

```
let positionClicked = 3
let snapshotClicked = list[positionClicked]
let keyClicked = snapshotClicked.key
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Utfordringer")
            .child(keyClicked)
            .removeValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "get past" child keys.  And T=there are no wildcards in Realtime Database.  If you want to delete a node, you have to be able to build a full path to that node, with all the child key names in that path.  If you don't know one of the child nodes in the path, you can't delete it.

It sounds like you'll find some way to find the child you're looking for, perhaps with a query, then delete it once you know the name of that child.

Comment: I probably wrote that wrong. I just want to get to child kategori and utfordring so I can update those with updateChildren() or removeValue().

Comment: As I said, you will have to make query to find the name of the child node, then use that to delete it.